# Is bit shifting opposite from what I am expecting?

Tags: objective-c, enums, bitwise-operators

I did some tests with enums and bitwise operators today and to verify the functionality with Xcode I created a series of tests. Here's the full Gist which I will keep public.

https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/ede1f685018e953da8a4

For the enum I have set bit shifted values so that I can use bitwise operators to check values. Here is the typedef for the enum for MyState.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyState) {
    MyStateNone                 = 0,            // (0000 = 0)
    MyStateOn                   = (1 << 0),     // (1000 = 1)
    MyStateOff                  = (1 << 1),     // (0100 = 2)
    MyStateEnabled              = (1 << 2),     // (0010 = 4)
    MyStateDisabled             = (1 << 3),     // (0001 = 8)
    MyStateOnAndEnabled         = MyStateOn | MyStateEnabled,   // 5
    MyStateOffAndDisabled       = MyStateOff | MyStateDisabled  // 10
};
```

You can see that the on, off, enabled and disabled state are in sequence which would allow for shifting the values to change states from On and Enabled to Off and Disabled. The bits would go from 1010 to 0101.

I believe that should be a right shift (>>) but in my tests it is a left shift which works. Below are the test functions. Why is it working with the opposite shift operators from what I am expecting? Maybe my understanding is opposite of what it does. That seems to be the case.

Left shift seems to put a 0 on the left side, moving all bits to the right. I thought it meant that left shift meant all bits moved left. Could someone clarify? Thanks.

```
- (void)testBitShiftingToOnAndEnabled {
    // Note: shifting enum values is ill advised but useful academically

    MyState state = MyStateOffAndDisabled; // 0101 (10)
    NSLog(@"state: %lu", (unsigned long)state);
    // if both values are shifted 1 to the right it becomes off and disabled
    state >>= 1; // 1010 (5)
    NSLog(@"state: %lu", (unsigned long)state);

    XCTAssert(state == MyStateOnAndEnabled, @"Pass");
    XCTAssert(state == 5, @"Pass");
}

- (void)testBitShiftingToOffAndDisabled {
    // Note: shifting enum values is ill adviced but useful academically

    MyState state = MyStateOnAndEnabled; // 1010 (5)
    NSLog(@"state: %lu", (unsigned long)state);
    // if both values are shifted 1 to the left it becomes off and disabled
    state <<= 1; // 0101 (10)
    NSLog(@"state: %lu", (unsigned long)state);

    XCTAssert(state == MyStateOffAndDisabled, @"Pass");
    XCTAssert(state == 10, @"Pass");
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your binary literals in little-endian form?  The tradition for number systems utilizing indo-arabic numerals is to write them in big-endian order.

Comment: The terms "left shift" and "right shift" refer to the direction bits "move" when laid out from left to right in big-endian order, regardless of the endianness of the machine (which generally refers to byte-order endianness, not bit-order endianness).  A left-shift in big endian notation is equivalent to a right shift in little-endian notation, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `1<<2` means to shift the bits for the value `1` to the left 2 places. Think of the `<<` as arrows pointing left.

The value `1` in binary (8-bits):

```
00000001
```

Now shift the bits to the left 2 places:

```
00000100
```

That's why `1<<2` changes the value 1 to 4.

Your misunderstanding is that the bit ordering starts on the right and goes to the left.

Updated comments for your code:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyState) {
    MyStateNone                 = 0,            // (0000 = 0)
    MyStateOn                   = (1 << 0),     // (0001 = 1)
    MyStateOff                  = (1 << 1),     // (0010 = 2)
    MyStateEnabled              = (1 << 2),     // (0100 = 4)
    MyStateDisabled             = (1 << 3),     // (1000 = 8)
    MyStateOnAndEnabled         = MyStateOn | MyStateEnabled,   // 5
    MyStateOffAndDisabled       = MyStateOff | MyStateDisabled  // 10
};
```

BTW - this is basic C. None this is specific to Objective-C.

Comment: I have my bits in the wrong order? So 0001 is 1 and 0010 is 2? That is starting bring back some memories from long ago. I expect most of this code will also work in C. It is just NS_OPTIONS which I is likely specific to Objective-C or at least Apple's platform. It simply compacts the typedef. Thanks for clearing this up.